# ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I got a problem with my code it says :  ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined variable: tpId in /tmxpage/apache/htdocsEDI/Editracker/src/Matrix/MatrixEdiBundle/Controller/MatrixController.php line 435 , im new to symfony and I don't know why,.

here is my code for MatrixController.php :

```
public function checkDocumentAction($docType, $direction, $senderId, $receiverId) {
    $response = 0;
    $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $temp = $em
        ->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiInterchangeId')
        ->findInterchangeId($senderId);
    $countTemp = count($temp);
    if($temp != null) {
      if($countTemp == 1) {
        foreach($temp as $key) {
          $tpId = $key->getEdiTradingPartner();
        }
      } else {
        $temp1 = $em
          ->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiInterchangeId')
          ->findInterchangeId($receiverId);
        $countTemp1 = count($temp1);
        if($temp1 != null) {
          if($countTemp1 == 1) {
            foreach($temp1 as $key) {
              $tpId = $key->getEdiTradingPartner();
            }
          } elseif($countTemp1 > 1) {
            foreach($temp1 as $key) {
              $temp2 = $key->getEdiTradingPartner();
              $temp3 = $em
                  ->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiInterchangeId')
                  ->findTradingPartner($temp2, $senderId);
              $countTemp3 = count($temp3);
              if($countTemp3 == 1) {
                foreach($temp3 as $key) {
                  $tpId = $key->getEdiTradingPartner();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if ($tpId != null) {
        $result = $em
            ->getRepository('MatrixEdiBundle:EdiTradingPartnerTransactions')
            ->getTpTrans($tpId, $docType, $direction);
        // if ($result != null) {
        //   $response = 1;
        // }
        if ($result != null) {
          foreach ($result as $key) {
            $isRequired = $key->getIsRequired();
            if ($isRequired == 1) {
              $response = 1;
            } else {
              $response = 2;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return new Response($response);
}
```

> it's a function inside the matrixcontroller.php

Here is my snippet for rejectedTrans.html.twig where the tpId is rendered, coz it also says :An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined variable: tpId, :

```
{% if transaction != null %}
    {% for trans in transaction %}
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 8%;">
          {{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getTradingPartnerName', {
              'timexID' : trans.ediTransaction.receiverId,
              'customerID' : trans.ediTransaction.senderId
          })) }}
        </td>
        {% set result=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getFile', {
            'fileName' : trans.ediTransaction.fileName,
            'senderId': trans.ediTransaction.senderId ,
            'receiverId' : trans.ediTransaction.receiverId,
            'gsNumber' : trans.ediTransaction
        }))|split('+', 4) %}
```

Comment: You do realise that when $tpId is being set, it will only ever be set to the last value in the array's in the foreach loops? Also, you're doing queries within loops which is very bad practice, you could remove these loops if the queries were written correctly to join in the data that you're querying within the loops.

Answer (score 0):

$tpId initializes only in conditions. So if all conditions is false, variable will not be defined.

Initialize it with null

```
public function checkDocumentAction($docType, $direction, $senderId, $receiverId) {
    $response = 0;
    $tpId = null;

...
```